# Refactoring method in ApplicationController for Rails App

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Here is a method I have in my `ApplicationController`, but it's "ugly" and needs some cleanup.

```
  def user_root_path
    return root_url unless user_signed_in?
    return admin_root_url if current_user.admin?
    return contributor_dashboard_url if current_user.athlete_contributor? && !current_user.class.name.eql?("Athlete")
    return school_admin_athletes_path if current_user.role?("School Admin")

    case current_user.class.name
    when "Athlete"
      if current_user.username.present?
        edit_vitals_athlete_profile_path
      else
        account_finalize_path
      end
    when "HighSchoolCoach"
      school_admin_athletes_path
    when "CollegeCoach"
      if current_user.sports.blank? || current_user.college_id.blank?
        account_finalize_path
      else
        search_index_path
      end
    else
      root_url
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this with a combination of inheritance and duck typing.

- Use a base method on a `User` class `root_path` to be your entry point.
- Pull out that nasty "signed out" user concept to a `NullUser` object, it is safer than passing nils around or constantly calling `user_signed_in?` everywhere.
- Delegate from the `root_path` method in the base class to `specific_root_path` in subclasses once you are past your "early exit" logic.

---

```
# application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_current_user

  def user_root_path
    @user.root_path
  end

  def set_current_user
    @user = current_user
    @user ||= NullUser.new
  end
end
```

---

```
# user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def admin?
    # your admin logic
  end

  def root_path
    return admin_root_url  if self.admin?
    return school_admin_athletes_path if self.role?("School Admin") 
    if self.athlete_contributor? &&
      !self.class.name.eql?("Athlete")
      return contributor_dashboard_url
    end

    specific_root_path
  end

  def specific_root_path
    root_url
  end
end

class NullUser
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def root_path
    root_url
  end
end
```

---

```
# athlete.rb

class Athlete < User

  def specific_root_path
    if self.username.present?
      edit_vitals_athlete_profile_path
    else
      account_finalize_path
    end
  end

end
```

---

```
# high_school_coach.rb

class HighSchoolCoach < User

  def specific_root_path
    school_admin_athletes_path
  end

end
```

---

```
# college_coach.rb

class CollegeCoach < User
  def specific_root_path
    if self.sports.blank? || self.college_id.blank?
      account_finalize_path
    else
      search_index_path
    end
  end
end
```

---

This logic should be equivalent to your original logic, if it isn't, it is pretty close.